# Let $A$ be nonempty and bounded above s.t. $s=sup A$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that $S \in \overline{A}$

My thought is to let $L$ be the set of limit points for $A$.
There are two cases, where $A$ is open or $A$ is closed.
The case for where $A$ is open i.e. $s \notin A$: We can show that $s$ is a limit point for $A$

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $s$ is the supremum, $\exists a \in A$ so that $s-\epsilon < a$. Since $s \notin A$, $a \neq s$ and $V_\epsilon (s)$ intersects $A$ at a point not $s$, hence $s$ is a limit point for $A$ and $s \in \overline{A}$.

As far as when $s \in A$ I'm having trouble visualizing *why* $s \in A$ and $s \in \overline{A}$. Some help there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that $s\in\bar{A}$. Let's proceed by contradiction. Assume that $s\notin \bar{A}$. Then, since $\bar{A}$ is closed, there must be some $\epsilon>0$ such that $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\bar{A}$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. By the definition of the supremum, there must be, as you noted, an $a\in A$ satisfying $s-\frac{1}{N}<a\leq s$. But this means that $a\in(s-\frac{1}{N},s+\frac{1}{N})\subset(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, contradicting that $a\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sup A$ always exists regardless of the boundedness of $A$.

To show that $s \in A^-$, observe that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists x \in A\mid s - x < \epsilon$, so choosing $\epsilon = 1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, \dots$ results in a sequence converging to $s$.

Comment: Are you sure that the supremum exist is A is not bounded? The set $\Bbb R$ have some supremum?

Comment: @Masacroso $\sup\mathbb{R} = \infty$. It is in the extended reals. Similarly $\sup\emptyset = -\infty$, while $\emptyset$ is bounded.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip.